# sprintf to copy int into string in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert an integer to string using `sprintf` but it's not working as expected.

When I input a number it works fine, I can show the number on screen. But if I input a string it always shows `"2"` on screen.

I was planning to get the string so that I can check if it's a number or not with the `isdigit()` function.

Tried `itoa()` too but it was pretty much the same story.

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    char string[31];

    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    sprintf(string, "%d", num);

    printf("%s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

If I input `2999`: it shows `"2999"`

If I input `"dog"`: it shows `"2"`

How can I get that string? For what I've seen it should work, perhaps something's up with my IDE? I have Code Blocks 16.01.

Comment: `scanf("%d"` means to scan an integer ... `dog` is not an integer. You could use `fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);` instead, and then use `sscanf` to check if there is a number in the string.

Comment: I'd bet that if you say `int num = 5;` up top, the output from `"dog"` will be `5` as well, yeah?

Comment: So it will never get any kind of string that way? That's disappointing. I'll look into the option you suggest, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yep still no dog with 5...  I cry evrytime :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int num;` leaves `num` uninitialized. When you input `"dog"`, the `scanf` operation doesn't match anything against `num`, so nothing is stored in it. Thus when you `printf` `num` it is still uninitialized and the value you get is garbage.

You could test for this by examining the return of `scanf`. `scanf` will return the number of successful matches, which you should expect to be `1` if a number was entered

```
printf("Number: ");
if (scanf("%d",&num) != 1) {
    puts("You didn't enter a number!");
}
```

For a better proof it is not being set, try initializing `num` to something and see what gets printed

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int num = 5; // I'm initializing to 5
  char string[31];

  printf("Number: ");
  scanf("%d",&num);

  sprintf(string, "%d", num);

  printf("%s", string);  // now this prints "5" if I input "dog"
  return 0;
}
```

For further evidence of this, running your original program through valgrind prints a bunch of errors about using an uninitialized value. I've edited out some of the noise in the below:

```
$ echo "dog" | valgrind ./a.out
==32450== 
==32450== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==32450==    at _itoa_word
==32450==    by vfprintf 
==32450==    by vsprintf
==32450==    by  sprintf
==32450==    by main
==32450== 
==32450== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==32450==    at vfprintf 
==32450==    by vsprintf
==32450==    by sprintf
==32450==    by main
```

To accomplish your goal of reading a string then checking it, you'll want to use `fgets` instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  char input[31];
  printf("Number: ");
  fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);  // read up to a line of input as a string
  if (isdigit(input[0])) {  // check if it's a number
    puts("this is a number (or at least starts with one)");
  } else {
    puts("this is not a number");
    return 1;
  }

  int num = 0;
  char string[31];

  sscanf(input, "%d", &num);  // now you can do the scanf on the input string

  sprintf(string, "%d", num);
  printf("%s", string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very enlightening answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at the return value from `scanf`.  It is likely returning zero.  It is failing and not storing a value in `num`.  The `2` is likely the indeterminate value that was on the stack when the program started.

If you want to read the value that was input, then use `fgets` to read the input into the buffer and then `sscanf` to extract it.